# How to enable pop-up window for more than 1000 features in ArcGIS Online

Tags: popup, arcgis-online

Is there any way to enable pop-up window in ArcGIS Online for more than 1000 features for layers' information?

When I try to add a shape file in arcgis.com to the map I get the message saying:

> The maximum  features allowed are 1000.

Comment: Can you link to any documentation about the feature you are asking about, and if such a limitation is also documented?

Answer (score 2):

Two possible workarounds for this limitation have been discussed in the **[ArcGIS Discussion Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/41778-1-000-feature-limit-in-ArcGIS-online)**:

- Create a service out of your data using ArcGIS for Server; or
- "With an organizational subscription, you'll be able to visualize your points by creating a hosted service out of your data rather than loading the data directly into the web map. The subscription gives you the ability to create a service, which is different than loading directly in the web map, which is what you can do without one."